# How to make when changing a phone number not jump the cursor to the end of the field?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a field to put a phone number with your right format and everything, but the problem is when you want to modify one of the phone numbers, it skips to the end of the field leaves delete or include numbers, but jump at the end automaticaly , please can someone help me?

Comment: solution: First get the initial position of the cursor (or the end of the selected range):

UITextRange *selectedRange = [textField selectedTextRange];
NSInteger offset = [textField offsetFromPosition:textField.endOfDocument toPosition:selectedRange.end];
After modifying the textField's text, reset the cursor position by using UITextPosition as follows:

UITextPosition *newPos = [textField positionFromPosition:textField.endOfDocument offset:offset];
textField.selectedTextRange = [textField textRangeFromPosition:newPos toPosition:newPos];

Answer (score 1):

this is a solution:

First get the initial position of the cursor (or the end of the selected range):

UITextRange *selectedRange = [textField selectedTextRange];
NSInteger offset = [textField offsetFromPosition:textField.endOfDocument toPosition:selectedRange.end];

After modifying the textField's text, reset the cursor position by using UITextPosition as follows:

UITextPosition *newPos = [textField positionFromPosition:textField.endOfDocument offset:offset];
textField.selectedTextRange = [textField textRangeFromPosition:newPos toPosition:newPos];

Answer (score 0):

Describe better what is your problem! Also you can check if that solves your problem

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2006/qa1454.html